# How to join csv and sum value in column using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
file1.csv
date        item1    spec    count
2019-03-29  book     blue     10
2019-03-30  shirt    green    11
...
2019-04-25  book     blue     20
2019-04-26  shirt    green    15
```

and another file csv like this:

```
file2.csv
date        item1    spec    count
2019-03-29  book     blue     5
2019-03-30  shirt    green    4
...
2019-04-25  book     blue     7
2019-04-26  shirt    green    8
```

and I want to combine that file to be like this:

```
fileResult.csv
date        item1    spec    count
2019-03-29  book     blue     15
2019-03-30  shirt    green    15
...
2019-04-25  book     blue     27
2019-04-26  shirt    green    23
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: `set_index('date')` for both df and then `df1.add(df2)` ??

Comment: you want to add on the basis of date or you want to match all column values then add count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read csv and save in dataframe
Concat both files using pd.concat()
groupby `date,item,spec` and sum the count using `groupby()`

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv')
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
final_result= df3.groupby(['date','item','spec'],as_index=False)['count'].sum()
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Comment: This is a good solution, but not correct yet, this would duplicate each row. Dont use `transform`, just simple groupby with `as_index=False`

Comment: @Erfan you are right I have updated the code
Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

If both of your dataframes have the same *shape* (same amount of rows, columns) and the data is *aligned* as in your example, we can simply do:

```
df1['count'] = df1['count'] + df2['count']
```

---

```
print(df1)
         date  item1   spec  count
0  2019-03-29   book   blue     15
1  2019-03-30  shirt  green     15
2  2019-04-25   book   blue     27
3  2019-04-26  shirt  green     23
```

**Else** use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
final = df1.merge(df2, on=['date', 'item1', 'spec'])
final['count'] = final.pop('count_x')+ final.pop('count_y')
```

---

```
         date  item1   spec  count
0  2019-03-29   book   blue     15
1  2019-03-30  shirt  green     15
2  2019-04-25   book   blue     27
3  2019-04-26  shirt  green     23
```

Comment: `final['count'] = final.pop('count_x'])+ final.pop('count_y')` will save you the `drop()` line :)

Comment: Nice one @anky_91 have to keep `.pop` in mind, not using it enough. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the csv: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
2. Append the data frames to each other: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html
3. Group by date, item1, spec and use sum as aggregator: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html